# Enable textbox from checkbox inside ItemsControl.ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have an ItemsControl that I've bound to an IEnumerable. In the DataTemplate, I am creating a CheckBox for each Enum.

For ONE of the Enum's, I want to enable a textbox outside of the ItemsControl if it is checked. How can I do this?

Comment: Your IEnumerable, is an enumeration of the values of your Enum or is it a collection of items that have a property of type YourEnum?

Comment: Enumeration of the values of my enum

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel to manipulate this. You won't be able to affect an element outside the name scope (I.E outside the `DataTemplate`) via XAML

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, but guess I have no choice. Thanks HighCore.